# Error when trying to export pix2pix model to tensorflow.js

Tags: tensorflow

[Error shown: subprocess.CalledProcessError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMIQg.png)

Comment: I'm not sure what to do from here. Any help in solving this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.